# scipy.stats.mode has 'TypeError :unorderable types str() > float()'

Tags: python

the code is

```
import scipy.stats as stats
stats.mode(df['Gender']')
```

three are some null in df['Gender'],and the problem is 'TypeError: unorderable types: str() > float()'.[scipy(0.19.1) python3.5.2]
How?
please,THx.

Comment: Provide sample data please: [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

As you said the error arises because there are missing values in your data. I am assuming you are using pandas dataframe. To take the mode, you can omit the rows which have missing values.

```
stats.mode(df.loc[~(df['G'].isnull()),'G'])
```